# Location tag in web.config for authorization

Tags: asp.net, authorization

In project their is a folder namely customer, inside there is a file namely register.aspx. In web.config have the configuration check like follows

```
    <location path="Customer">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>

<location path="Customer/Register.aspx">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="?"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Even i have authorized the register.aspx for unauthorized users but is expecting to authorize. Can any body explain it.

Comment: To clarify the issue, all access is being denied across the board?

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a Web.Config file in `Customer` folder and add

```
<location path="Register.aspx">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="?"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: The above config, will allow the entire folder access to un-authorized user right. so he can directly call the customer information screen without authenticated.

Comment: @VIJAYASHANKAR you have to set authorization for each page in the `Customer` folder. Or move the `Register.aspx` page to a different folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try switching order of those location nodes.  Put allow Register first, and deny Customer second.